# Can't pass Auth::user()->id on form submission

Tags: php, laravel

when I DD each variable i can see value including user_id
it just wont store in db...I am not sure what is causing this... userd_id is always storing with 0 value

View :

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'UserCommentController@store']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::hidden('post_id', $post->id, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::hidden('user_id', $value = Auth::id(), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows'=> 2]) !!}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Submit Comment', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'post_id' => $request->post_id,
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'body' => $request->body
    ];
    Comment::create($data);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

DB :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: In your controller you can merge the user id on the `$request->all()`. That is also a safer solution that just hiding a form field

Comment: Do `dd(Auth::user())` and check what is the results on loading the page

Comment: question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Is `Auth::id()` working? I'm not sure, but I always use `Auth::user()->id`;

2) In the comment controller try to add the following line: `protected $fillable = ['user_id']`. If you already have $fillable set, just add 'user_id' to the array. That's something I forget sometimes.

Comment: Thank you!!! had forgot user_id on the fillable after i made some changes on the db table structure..